# Error using \edtext in \eledsection with titlesec

Tags: titlesec, reledmac

When using titlesec with reledmac, it appears an error if one tries to add an \edtext to a chapter or section command. It says "\edtext outside numbered paragraph".

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{titlesec}


\usepackage{reledmac}
\usepackage{reledpar}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{pages}
        \begin{Leftside}
            \beginnumbering
            
            \pstart
            \eledsection{Title left \edtext{error}{\Cfootnote{not ok}}}
            \pend
            
            \endnumbering   
        \end{Leftside}
        \begin{Rightside}
            \beginnumbering
            
            \pstart
            \eledsection{Title right}
            \pend
                    
            \endnumbering   
        \end{Rightside}
    \end{pages}
    \Pages
    
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Titlesec and eledsection are not compatible. It is a knew feature request, but sorry, no time for it.

Comment: Do you know of any alternative packages that are compatible and can be used to style the chapters and sections?

Comment: unfortunatly, not.

Comment: @Maïeul FWIW I've been able to style chapters and section titles using memoir's built-in tools, and it has worked great