# Error when using \edtext in eledsection with memoir and babel

Tags: memoir, babel, reledmac, reledpar

I know something similar was asked [before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/630705/error-using-edtext-in-eledsection-with-titlesec) but it seems that this error is caused by something different. It says:

```
Package reledmac Error: 
\edtext outside numbered paragraph (\pstart ... \pend). \end
```

In the MWE, `\edtext` works inside `\eledsection` only if babel is deactivated. Do you know if there is a workaround?

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{memoir}
    
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel} % Works if line commented out
    
    \usepackage{reledmac}
    \usepackage{reledpar}
    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{pages}
            \begin{Leftside}
                \beginnumbering
                \pstart
                    \eledsection{Title \edtext{error}{\Afootnote{not working}} left}
                \pend
                \endnumbering   
            \end{Leftside}
            \begin{Rightside}
                \beginnumbering
                \pstart
                    \eledsection{Title right}
                \pend
                \endnumbering   
            \end{Rightside}
        \end{pages}
        \Pages  
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Please cite the error you get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spanish module for `babel` changes the behaviour of `<` and `>` to facilitate quoting. In fact, `<<` and `>>` are defined as shorthands for `\begin{quoting}` and `\end{quoting}` respectively, and introduce an environment (see the [documentation](https://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/babel-contrib/spanish/spanish.pdf#page=12)).

This is known to cause incompatibilities with other packages (f.i. see [Spanish babel and chemformula package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157097/)).

I'm not sure what exactly this breaks in the innards of `reledmac` (possibly, it messes with a "greater" or "lesser" sign in some formula comparing the values of line numbers).

Anyway, restoring the normal behavior of the characters solves the problem. The answer I linked also offers a hint on how to do it, if you don't require the special quotation mechanism offered by `babel/spanish`. Use the option `es-noquoting` or (if you have version 3.9 or later) the modifier `.noquoting` after `spanish`.

```
%\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel} % before 3.9
\usepackage[spanish.noquoting]{babel} % with 3.9
```

Comment: Thank you so, so much. It was driving me nuts! It seems that that was the problem. I can use csquotes instead of the quotation mechanism of babel.